# Calling an SQL adapter from another SQL adapter doesnt work

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

pls. is there any idea or suggestion wy call from an SQL adapter to another SQL adapter doesnt work ?
i use WL.Server.invokeProcedure.({adapter : "SQL_Adapter",procedure : "procedure name in the another adapter"}). it seems that function doesnt check the existence of the adapter and procedure parameters and work with any arbitrary string even for non-existing adapter/procedure. Result is always undefined object returned from the call

i am using Worklight 6.1.0.01.20140311-2356 on Windows server
both adapters works fine and are used regularly from client devices
the "server" adapter (MS SQL) is used for push notification and defines event source
the "client" adapter (DB2) is normal one.

there is piece of code:

```
var result = getAllUsersFromSQLPushNotificationAdapter();

if (result){
    WL.Logger.info("test1" + result.isSuccessful); //i got false
    WL.Logger.info("test2" + result.errorMessages); //i got undefined

    WL.Logger.info("test3 " + result.resultSet); //i got undefined
    //result = result["invocationResult"]["resultSet"];

    for (var i = 0; i < result.resultSet.length; i++) {
        //result[i].Category ";
    }

    WL.Logger.info("Number of users: " + result.resultSet.length);
}   

function getAllUsersFromSQLPushNotificationAdapter(){


    return WL.Server.invokeProcedure({
        adapter : "CZU_SQL",
        procedure : "getAllUsers"});    

}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.In `getDataSuccess()` get the results and use it.

```
var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'ADAPTER_NAME',
        procedure : 'PROCEDURE_NAME'    
    };

WL.Server.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
    onSuccess : getDataSuccess,
    onFailure : getDataFailure,
});
```

For debugging purpose check the Success and failure function results. if you are not able to call another adapter procedure please post the error from failure function.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work. i cant provide any return value.the caller function gets finished and nothing happens. Neither callback function got called (i can just check it on the console of the server via WL.server.log). But i should probably stated from beginning i am using that from event source kind adapter and my function runs scheduled (WL.Server.createEventSource). but pls. back to my experience there is no difference when i call non-existing/arbitrary remote adapter/function. Is there a problem, maybe? thank you